# binding input text box to mysql data using jquery ajax

Tags: mysql, jquery

Hey can Anyone help me? I am working with a combobox I wanted when the user select specific value the input box will be bind with corresponding value from the combo box. How do I accomplish this ?

```
 <li>
      <label for="name">Doctor Name:</label>
       <select  class="leav" ID="combobox" name="doctor">
           <option></option>
              <?php
                foreach($db->search_doctors_name() as $data) {
                echo "<option value=\"".$data."\">".$data."</option>\n </br>";
                }
                ?>
       </select>
 </li>
 <li>
       <label for="name">User Name: </label>
       <input   type="text" id="unm" required name="admin_name"/>
 </li> 

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".leav").focusout(function() {
           ---ajax function-- (SELECT FROM table)---
        var name = from_AJAX_function               
        $( "#unm" ).val(name);
      });
   });
 </script>
```

I want to bind the inputbox when lost focus/leave cursor from combobox.

Comment: but I wanted the $("#unm").val($(this).val()); the value from the database (mysql) sample I had 3 doctors Dr. Jane, Dr. John, Dr Mac when I chose Dr. Jane the .change or lostfocus the input box will bind admin_name = jane

Comment: i think you should give the change a try :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <li>
      <label for="name">City Name:</label>
       <select  class="leav" ID="combobox" name="doctor">
           <option>Tehran</option>
           <option>Shiraz</option>
           <option>Isfahan</option>
       </select>
 </li>
 <li>
       <label>User Name: </label>
       <input type="text" id="unm"/>
 </li>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".leav").change(function() {
            $("#unm").val($(this).val());
        });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: thanks but I wanted a value fetch from mysql database on the selected value from the combobox